# How do I add two icons in individual items of Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I want two icons in an item. Do I have to use fragments to achieve this? I need to add one image of logout and one arrow image to the right. Please Help !!

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cONfr.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

We can simply use **app:actionLayout** and insert layout with it.
for example (Individual item of Navigation Drawer) :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navId"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_ID"
    android:title="Name"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/layout"

    />
```

I have used a textview and simply added the icon with drawableRight

layout.xml

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_two"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this is useful. but one question why text view cant we take any other controller like image view or any other?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to create a custom layout and inflate it to your navigation drawer. Thats option one, second option would be to create a background image with the arrow on the right side and use it in the menu

Comment: How to inflate a custom layout to navigation drawer?